# how to Import node_modules without errors

Tags: javascript, import, node-modules

app.js:

```
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";
```

Error: Failed to resolve module specifier "@supabase/supabase-js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

```
--node-modules
   @supabase
     supabase-js
    ....other modules
--website
    index.html
    app.js
--package.json
--package-lock.json
```

Comment: How do you run your project? babel, webpack, node, or ...?
If you have any config files please share that too.

Comment: Should I run my project by webpack or node to import any node module ? do you mean these config files ? 
`
folder 
--node-modules
   @supabase
     supabase-js
    ....other modules
--website
    index.html
    app.js
--package.json
--package-lock.json
`

Comment: You need a bundler to merge all your JS files into one single JS file and then link to that single JS file. you can't use import just like that in all browsers, search and read about bundler to get more informations

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't provided much details, I can't explain why your code is not accepting the "bare import" (when you import a module just by name) 
But you can solve it by importing via relative path:
From app.js point of view, you first need to move up one folder "../", then enter "node-modules".

```
import { createClient } from "../node-modules/@supabase/supabase-js";
```